# Is it possible for a base class to provide an iterator interface that derived classes implement?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am porting this code from Visual C++ 6.0 (it also worked with an older GCC++) to Visual Studio 2010 C++. The code compiles but throws an exception.

I have an base class, CncMatchedQueryAtom. This class is used contain matches of different types of target atoms (this is a graph matching application) for 99% of the cases there is a one to one match between the query and the target. This is handled by the derived class, CncMatchedQueryAtomSimple. This class works great. The problem is that some query atoms match groups of atoms, this  is handled by the class, CncMatchedQueryAtomGroup. This class contains a vector with the matched atoms. I want the iterator class defined within the base class to encapsulate the vector iterator in the derived class such that begin() returns the vector begin() and the end returns the vector's end().
The old version has problems on the end() at runtime because it does the conversion by:

```
return &*group.end();
```

Which is no longer allowed by Visual C++
So how can a base class specify an iterator that derived classes can implement? This doesn't seem very obvious to me, but I'm new to C++. Nor is it something that seasoned C++ developers that I work with know of either.

Basically, I want the base class to have methods that provide begin and end functions that the derived classes implement.

Here is the code:

```
 class CncMatchedQueryAtom
{
protected:
int notBlockAllocated;
public:
int allocateIndividually() const
{
    return notBlockAllocated;
}
const CncAtom *queryAtom;

CncAtom *queryAtomVolitile() const
{
    return (CncAtom*)queryAtom;
}

// set when the class has been allocated by newing

// intialize all default constructors to be notBlockAllocated
CncMatchedQueryAtom()
    : notBlockAllocated(1)
    , queryAtom(NULL) // i don't think this needs to be initialized to null
{
}

CncMatchedQueryAtom(int noBlock)
    : notBlockAllocated(noBlock)
    , queryAtom(NULL) // i don't think this needs to be initialized to null
{
}

// may not need this now that it's a virtual!
CncMatchedQueryAtom(const CncMatchedQueryAtom &that)
    : queryAtom(NULL)
{
    *this = that;
}

// this needs to be virtual so when delete CncMatchedQueryAtom is called
// the virtual calss members are destructed too
virtual ~CncMatchedQueryAtom()
{
}

virtual void dump() const =0;
virtual void clearMapping() =0;
virtual CncMatchedQueryAtom *newCopy() const =0;
virtual void coverHits(class CncTarget *) const = 0;
// iterates over all matched target atoms for this query atom
class iterator  
{
private:
    CncMatchedTargetAtom *ptr;

public:

    iterator()
    {
    }
    iterator(const CncMatchedTargetAtom *targetAtom)  // constructor from a   target ptr
        :ptr((CncMatchedTargetAtom *)targetAtom)
    {
    }
    iterator(const iterator &oldOne)
        :ptr(oldOne.ptr)
    {
    }
    ~iterator()
    {
    }

    int operator==(const iterator &that) const
    {
        return ptr==that.ptr;
    }
    int operator!=(const iterator &that) const
    {
        return ptr!=that.ptr;
    }

    const CncMatchedTargetAtom &operator*() const
    {
        return *ptr;
    }

    iterator operator++(int NotUsed)  // post increment
    {
        iterator returnValue(*this);
        ++ptr;
        return returnValue;
    }
    iterator &operator++()  // pre increment
    {
        ++ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    int operator<(const iterator &rhs) const
    {
        return (this->ptr < rhs.ptr);
    }


    CncMatchedTargetAtom *operator->()
    {
        return ptr;
    }
};

virtual iterator begin() const =0;
virtual iterator end() const =0;
virtual int size() const = 0;
virtual double molecularWeight() const = 0;

const CncAtom *getFirstTargetAtom() const
{
    return (*begin()).matchedTargetAtom;
}
CncAtom *getFirstTargetAtomVolitile() const
{
    return (CncAtom*)getFirstTargetAtom();
}

}; // class CncMatchedQueryAtom
class CncMatchedQueryAtomSimple : public CncMatchedQueryAtom
{
public:
// we need a constructor here since this is allocated with blockAlloc
CncMatchedQueryAtomSimple()
    : CncMatchedQueryAtom(0)
{
}

// we use simple.targetAtom as a temporary variable
// used to pass to matching functions
CncMatchedTargetAtom simple;

void clearIt()
{
    queryAtom=NULL;
    notBlockAllocated=0;
}

// if queryAtom is an element-type atom (or Lp or A atom)
void dump() const;
void clearMapping()
{
}
CncMatchedQueryAtom *newCopy() const
{
    // since this is usually not allocatedIndividually I'll set
    // the notBlockAllocatedFlag on the copy to be sure if this
    // does happen it will individually deallocate it
    CncMatchedQueryAtomSimple *retVal = new CncMatchedQueryAtomSimple(*this);
    retVal->notBlockAllocated = 1;
    return (CncMatchedQueryAtom *)retVal;
}

void coverHits(class CncTarget *) const;

iterator begin() const
{
    return &simple;
}

iterator end()  const
{
    return &simple+1;
}

int size() const
{
    return 1;
}

double molecularWeight() const
{
    return CncMolGetAtomicMassAve(simple.matchedTargetAtom->getAtomicNumber());
}
}; // class CncMatchedQueryAtomSimple
class CncMatchedQueryAtomGroup : public CncMatchedQueryAtom
{
public:

// if queryAtom is an R- or X-group searching for 
std::vector<CncMatchedTargetAtom> group;

void dump() const;

void clearMapping()
{
    group.clear();
}
CncMatchedQueryAtom *newCopy() const
{
    return new CncMatchedQueryAtomGroup(*this);
}

void coverHits(class CncTarget *) const;

iterator begin() const
{
    return &*group.begin();
}

iterator end() const
{
            // this is a hack, works with Visual C++ 6.0 and older GCC++ but not VS C++ 2010
    return &*group.end(); // Throws error at runtime!   Iterator Not Dereferencable
}

int size() const
{
    return group.size();
}

double molecularWeight() const
{
    double sum=0;
    std::vector<CncMatchedTargetAtom>::const_iterator q;
    for (q=group.begin()
        ; q!=group.end()
        ; ++q)
    {
        sum += CncMolGetAtomicMassAve(q->matchedTargetAtom->getAtomicNumber());
    }
    return sum;
}

}; // class CncMatchedQueryAtom
```

An example of how the iterator is called:

```
// Sample call to the iterator
// (*elem)->getMatchedAtom() returns a CncMatchedQueryAtom *

CncMatchedQueryAtom::iterator atomMatched;

// welp it looks like we have to do these
//(*elem)->getFirstTargetAtom
for (atomMatched=(*elem)->getMatchedAtom()->begin()
     ; atomMatched!=(*elem)->getMatchedAtom()->end()  // Runtime exception here!
     ; ++atomMatched)
{
existenceFingerprint.setBit(
        atomMatched->matchedTargetAtom->indexInStructure);
}
```

Thanks, hopefully this isn't too much code...

Comment: Google for `any_iterator`. There's quite a few implementations available to pick from.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert iterators from one container into iterators to another container.

It used to work with VC6, because they happened to use a pointer as `vector::iterator`. Later versions have an iterator class where the conversion does not work.

Comment: To reemphasize, it was _never_ legal code, and was never guaranteed to work in VC6 either.

Comment: Right, a pointer is a kind of random access iterator that is a valid choice for `vector::iterator`. That a pointer can be assigned a pointer to another container is not part of the iterator contract. It just worked by accident for VC6.

Comment: This code also worked with gcc. What I want if for the base class to provide an iterator "interface" to proxy the the real iterators. Is this not possible in C++? Kind of defeats the purpose of objects.